# unity 3d cast object to float

Tags: c#, csv, unity-game-engine

im trying to read csv files and assigns the data read as a Vector 3 input data. From my understanding unity classify the data read from csv file as 'object' while the input data for Vector 3 function is in float. How do i convert these data as float values? the example of the code is here

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class readnmove : MonoBehaviour {

public float lat;
public float lon;
public float alt;
public float speed;
void Awake() {



}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {




    List<Dictionary<string,object>> data = CSVReader.Read ("cuba");

    for(var i=0; i < data.Count; i++) {
        print ("time " + data[i]["time"] + " " +
               "x " + data[i]["x"] + " " +
               "y " + data[i]["y"] + " " +
               "z " + data[i]["z"]);

        lat = data[i]["x"];
        lon = data[i]["y"];
        alt = data[i]["z"];

        transform.Translate(new Vector3 (lat, lon, alt)*speed*Time.deltaTime);


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`float.Parse(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [`float.TryParse(string, out float)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, in your case you will get:

```
lat = float.Parse(data[i]["x"].ToString());
lon = float.Parse(data[i]["y"].ToString());
alt = float.Parse(data[i]["z"].ToString());
```